# How to store image blob data in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a requirement to store image blob data in a table. I know storing an image in blob format within a database table is not best practice. But doing so is a client requirement. I am using ColdFusion 10 and SQL Server 2008. I have used this snippet to insert the image blob data in SQL server .

```
<cfimage action="read" name="imdata" source="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\a.jpg" >

<cfquery datasource="localdsn">
  INSERT INTO imtbl(image)
  VALUES #imageGetBlob(imdata)#
</cfquery>
```

But it is throwing error

`ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings.`

I have also tried using `#toString(imageGetBlob(imdata))#` Still no success.

I have gone through https://forums.adobe.com/thread/60629 But can not find any solution.

Comment: Did you enable the BLOB setting on your ColdFusion datasource?

Comment: Have you tried parameterising the blog with cfqueryparam? Something like `<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_blob" value="#imageGetBlob(imdata)#">` might help expose whats going on.

Comment: @Miguel-F: Yes I have enabled it , Still not working,

Comment: @Twillen, Yes tried but not working.

Comment: did you try using <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_blob"
              value="#FileReadBinary(imdata)#">

Comment: @shemy: Yes tried just now , no success. Error is `An error occurred when performing a file operation readBinary on file C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/runtime/work/Catalina/localhost/tmp/coldfusion.image.Image@5a7a8fe3. `

Comment: Almost.  `FileReadBinary()` expects a file path. You are passing in an image variable. Get rid of the `cfimage` and use `FileReadBinary("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\a.jpg")` inside your cfqueryparam.  Also, you obviously need parenthesis in your `VALUES (...)` clause.

Comment: When a table contains a FILESTREAM column, each row must have a unique row ID. It is created by NEWID().

Comment: I would add the following notice: If you use the image type in SQL Server (will be removed in a future version), please replace it with varbinary(max) - VarBinary vs Image SQL Server Data Type to Store Binary Data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I have fixed the issue. Two things I have done is,

1. I have enabled BLOB settings for the data source.
2. I have finally used this query

`<cfquery datasource="localdsn">
    INSERT INTO imtbl(image)
    VALUES (
     <cfqueryparam 
            cfsqltype="cf_sql_blob"
            value="#fileReadBinary('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\a.jpg')#">
    )
</cfquery>`